# FB mutual friends list

Tags: facebook, friend-list, facebook-friends

In facebook.  Friend A and Friend B have a mutual friend (Friend C).  When I go to see mutual friends with Friend A, Friend C does not show up on the list.  When Friend A goes to mutual friends with Friend B, Friend C shows up on the list.  Why is this?

Comment: Are you friend "B"?